# Run sonar on result of merge

Tags: sonarqube

I'm wondering if it's possible to run a Sonar scan on the result of a feature branch merge before actually performing the merge on remote?

I've tried searching everywhere and the closest thing I've found is quality gates, but I'm not sure that they can do what I'm asking, or if they just check sonar information from the feature branch without considering what files look like after a merge.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is it doing a merge locally, run sonar scan and then push it remote? Or does your scenario involves pull/merge requests?

Comment: you are looking for eg. githooks -> you could do a server side hook, which is running the scanner. If you want to merge in the end, is someting you can determine eg via api. but that is not part of your question :D